# Finding a range satisfying a property in faster than linear time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, range-query

Given an array A[] we need to find a range which has the maximum size and its minimum element is >= 1. We also need to update this range by decreasing all its elements by 1.

One idea I got is to keep a segment tree for efficient updates. But how do I get the range in <= logarithmic time?

Maybe we can use binary search here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in repeatedly finding the largest positive range and decrementing?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very interesting problem and I think it can be solved using Segment Tree.

Here are my idea (I hope it works fast enough):

For each segment, we need to store 4 info:

- leftmost index of number < 1
- rightmost index of number < 1
- max size for this segment (store as range a and b)
- lazy flag (true/false)

When we want to query max size, we can do recursive call to calculate the final answer.
Assume our method was calcAnswer(left,right).

resA = calcAnswer(left, mid);

resB = calcAnswer(mid+1,right);

Max size will be max(resA.max_size, resB.max_size, combine(resA.right_index,resB.left_index)).

If the number of elements in array A[] are small (N<=50000), we can use [Mo's Algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7383).

Comment: N is <= 10^5 in the problem.

Comment: if the problem comes from Online Judge, please kindly share to me. I want try to code my solution and submit it :). Thanks.

Comment: This problem might have a lot simpler solution per se, considering the fact that it is Div2 C

Comment: Yes, I just solved the problem using optimized BruteForce (156 ms). No need to coding Segment Tree.